# PHP return floating point number as time?

Tags: php

I want to import excel sheet values to MySQL table through PHP. There is column as time , value is 8:30 in excel. When I get that value to PHP it's represented as 0.35416666666667, 
I'm using phpexcel library .

```
$object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"]);
            foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){
                $highestrow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
                for ($row=2; $row<=2; $row++)
                {
                   echo $name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue();
}
}
```

I want that value to also be represented in PHP as 08:30:00

Comment: you might take a look at what 24 * 0.35416666666 evaluates to, that oughta give you a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel represents times as fractions of a day, so to convert an Excel timevalue to a PHP time string you need to convert it to seconds, then convert that to a date/time variable and output the time part of it. e.g.

```
$timevalue = 0.35416666666667;
echo gmdate('H:i', $timevalue * 24 * 3600);
```

Output:

```
08:30
```

Note we use `gmdate` rather than `date` to avoid issues with summer time adjusting the hour by 1.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0Jf1m)